# why index.html class="... sapUiMedia-Std-????"

Tags: sapui5

my index.html

```
[class="sap-phone sapUiTheme-sap_belize sap-ios sapUiMedia-Std-Tablet sapUiMedia-StdExt-Tablet"]
```

in iphone, but demo is

```
[class="sap-tablet  sap-desktop sap-combi sapUiTheme-sap_belize sapUiMedia-Std-Phone sapUiMedia-StdExt-Phone"]
```

why my "sapUiMedia-Std-Tablet" is not "sapUiMedia-Std-Phone"?

```
    sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
        new sap.tnt.ToolPage({
            header: new sap.tnt.ToolHeader("", {
                content: [
                    new sap.m.Button("", {
                        icon: "sap-icon://menu2",
                        type: sap.m.ButtonType.Transparent,
                        layoutData: new sap.m.OverflowToolbarLayoutData("", {
                            priority: sap.m.OverflowToolbarPriority.NeverOverflow
                        }),
                    })
                ]
            })
        }).placeAt("content");
    });
```

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit better? If you want to recognize how ui5 is recognizing your app, you could run in console dev tools sap.ui.Device.system.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, add sap.m.App to the index.html, than the problem was solved.

```
    sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
        new sap.m.App({
            pages: new sap.tnt.ToolPage({
                header: new sap.tnt.ToolHeader("", {
                    content: [
                        new sap.m.Button("", {
                            icon: "sap-icon://menu2",
                            type: sap.m.ButtonType.Transparent,
                            layoutData: new sap.m.OverflowToolbarLayoutData(
                                "", {
                                    priority: sap.m.OverflowToolbarPriority
                                        .NeverOverflow
                                }),
                        })
                    ]
                }),
                sideContent: new sap.tnt.SideNavigation("", {
                    item: new sap.tnt.NavigationList()
                })
            })
        }).placeAt("content");
    });
```

[effects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNouc.png)